# Understanding a case of Haskell Type-Ambiguity

Tags: haskell, ghc, ambiguity

I wrote a Haskell program and got a compile error I don't understand.

The program should:

- Get the command line arguments
- Concatenate tokenized arguments back to a single `String`
- Read the `String` into a `NestedList` data type
- Flatten the `NestedList` into a `List`
- Print the `List`

Unfortunately, it won't compile because of a type ambiguity.

**Haskell Code:**

```
{-
  Run like this:
  $ ./prog List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]]
  Output: [1,2,3,4,5]
-}
import System.Environment
import Data.List

data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
  deriving (Read)

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  print . flatten . read $ intercalate " " args

flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem x) = [x]
flatten (List x) = concatMap flatten x
```

**Compile Error:**

```
prog.hs:8:21:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (Read a0) arising from a use of `read' at prog.hs:8:21-24
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `print' at prog.hs:8:3-7
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `read'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `flatten . read'
    In the expression: print . flatten . read
```

Could someone help me understand how/why there is a type ambiguity and how I can make the code unambiguous.

Comment: What type do you think GHC should have found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ambiguous types occur in Haskell whenever a type variable disappears due to function application. The one you have here, `read/show` is common. Here's the problem:

Let's try to read a string, this operation has the type

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

such that if we give it a string we'll just get a type that looks like

```
read "()" :: Read a => a
```

In other words, the type system has not yet been able to pick a concrete type---it simply knows that whatever the answer is it must be `Read`able.

The problem is that if we turn back around and show this immediately we're applying a function

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

which also doesn't fully specify the type `a`. Combining them gives us

```
show (read "()") :: String
```

and we've lost all opportunities to decide upon what that intermediate type *should* have been.

Due to this ambiguity, Haskell disallows such expressions. You fix it by somehow interjecting a function which completely constrains the type. A common method is to use the function `asTypeOf`

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf = const
```

which ensures that the first and second arguments have the same type.

```
> show (read "()" `asTypeOf` ()) :: String
"()"
```

---

In your particular example you need to determine what the `a` is in `NestedList a`. An easy method to doing that is to explicitly give the type of `flatten` as a concrete type.

```
print . (flatten :: NestedList Int -> [Int]) . read $ concat args
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation! I removed the type ambiguity and it runs as expected!

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic problem. The "ad hoc" polymorphism of type classes makes type inference incomplete, and you've just been bitten. Let's look at the pieces.

```
read    :: Read x => String -> x
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
print   :: Show y => y -> IO ()
```

and we'll also have machine-generated instances for

```
Read a => Read (NestedList a)
Show a => Show (NestedList a)
Read a => Read [a]
Show a => Show [a]
```

Now let's solve the equations we get when we try to build the composition.

```
print   .     flatten              .   read

      y = [a]         NestedList a = x
```

That means we need

```
Show [a]                     Read (NestedList a)
```

and thus

```
Show a                       Read a
```

and we've used all our information without determining `a`, and hence the relevant `Read` and `Show` instances.

As J. Abrahamson has already suggested, you need to do something which determines the `a`. There are lots of ways to do it. I tend to prefer type annotations to writing strange terms whose only purpose is to make a type more obvious. I second the proposal to give a type to one of the components in the composition, but I'd probably pick `(read :: String -> NestedList Int)`, as that's the operation which introduces the ambiguously typed thing.

Comment: I used to like `asTypeOf` more until I started finding myself writing `(\`asTypeOf\` (undefined :: Etc))`. As it were, I had to change my example from `read "3"` to `read "()"` just to make it work. All said, type annotations are boss.