# Haskell class dependencies

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The following code doesnt compile:

```
class Foo f where
  getInt :: f -> Int

class Bar b where
  getFooFromBar :: Foo f => b -> f

someFunction :: Bar b => b -> Int
someFunction bar = getInt $ getFooFromBar bar
```

The error is `Could not deduce (Foo f) arising from a use of 'getInt' from the context (Bar b)`

I know I can fix the error by changing the class for `Bar` as follows:

```
class Foo f => Bar f b where
  getFooFromBar :: b -> f
```

But I would prefer if I didnt have to add `f` to all the instance signatures of `Bar`.

Is there a way to do this by only keeping the `Foo f` constraint only on the `getFooFromBar` signature, rather than the whole class?

Comment: I recommend you reconsider the type of `getFooFromBar` - it looks poised for an `Ambiguous type variable` error.

Comment: @Alec The full error indeed says `The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding a case of Haskell Type-Ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220655/understanding-a-case-of-haskell-type-ambiguity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I would prefer if I didnt have to add `f` to all the instance signatures of `Bar`.

Technically speaking, you don't need to do that to make your example compile. You can use a type annotation to specify which instance of `Foo` you are using in `someFunction`, solving the ambiguous type variable error. However, you have a deeper problem:

```
class Foo f where
  getInt :: f -> Int

class Bar b where
  getFooFromBar :: Foo f => b -> f
```

That is, for all practical purposes, impossible. The type of `getFooFromBar` says you can use it to produce a result of *any* type `f` that has an instance of `Foo`. But how will you materialise this value for any `f`? It is no use reaching for any specific instance when defining `getFooFromBar`, as all you will get from that is a `Couldn't match type ‘f’ with ‘Blah’` type error. The immediate solution to that is the one you suggested, for a different reason, in the question: specifying the instance of `Foo` to use through the `Bar` instance. You might find it nicer to do with a type family, rather than a multi-parameter type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class Foo f where
  getInt :: f -> Int

class Foo (FooBar b) => Bar b where
  type FooBar b :: *
  getFooFromBar :: b -> FooBar b

instance Foo Char where
   getInt = const 99

instance Bar Char where
  type FooBar Char = Char
  getFooFromBar = const 'a'

someFunction :: Bar b => b -> Int
someFunction = getInt . getFooFromBar
```

```
GHCi> someFunction 'z'
99
```